# insert into doesn´t work fine

Tags: php, insert

I have a code that help me to upload 6 files to the server and also add the information to the DataBase, the code works great when upload the files BUT when it will safe the information to the database just save the first one. Can you please help me,

This is the code

```
$i=0;
    while ($i<=10){
        if (isset($_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]) and ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]<>"")){
            $path[$i] = "../slider_new/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i];  
            $path[$i] =  str_replace(' ', '_',$path[$i]);
            copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][$i], $path[$i]);
            echo "Ruta :".$path[$i]."<BR/>";
            echo "File Name :".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]."<BR/>"; 
            echo "File Size :".$_FILES['ufile']['size'][$i]."<BR/>"; 
            echo "File Type :".$_FILES['ufile']['type'][$i]."<BR/>"; 
            echo "<img src=\"$path[$i]\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
            echo "<P>";
            $sql="INSERT INTO accommo_main_images (num,name,ruta) values('".$num."','".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]."','".$path[$i]."')";
            $res=mysqli_query($cnx,$sql);        
        }
        $i=$i+1;

    }
```

Comment: type var_dump($cnx, $res); after $res =.. What do you see as output?

Comment: num on accommo_main_images is varchar?... '".$num."'

Comment: Maybe missing something, but where is num initialized?

Comment: just remove single quote from  num fiels will worklike  $sql="INSERT INTO accommo_main_images (num,name,ruta) values(".$num.",'".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]."','".$path[$i]."')";

Comment: object(mysqli)[4]
 public 'affected_rows' => null
 public 'client_info' => null
 public 'client_version' => null
 public 'connect_errno' => null
 public 'connect_error' => null
 public 'errno' => null
 public 'error' => null
 public 'error_list' => null
 public 'field_count' => null
 public 'host_info' => null
 public 'info' => null
 public 'insert_id' => null
 public 'server_info' => null
 public 'server_version' => null
 public 'stat' => null
 public 'sqlstate' => null
 public 'protocol_version' => null
 public 'thread_id' => null
 public 'warning_count' => null
boolean true

Comment: the second one
object(mysqli)[4]
 public 'affected_rows' => null
 public 'client_info' => null
 public 'client_version' => null
 public 'connect_errno' => null
 public 'connect_error' => null
 public 'errno' => null
 public 'error' => null
 public 'error_list' => null
 public 'field_count' => null
 public 'host_info' => null
 public 'info' => null
 public 'insert_id' => null
 public 'server_info' => null
 public 'server_version' => null
 public 'stat' => null
 public 'sqlstate' => null
 public 'protocol_version' => null
 public 'thread_id' => null
 public 'warning_count' => null
boolean false

Comment: what does echo $sql shows?

Answer (score 0):

Change single quote from query in num field is

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO accommo_main_images (num,name,ruta) values(".$num.",'".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]."','".$path[$i]."')";min
```

You can print query like `echo $sql;` and check it in phpmyadmin or other tool will help remove error from query

Comment: Well that num is like a WE34EDER$

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the code work 100%, the problem was that I setup the nun like the Primary so for this reason just the first item was save, I added the "id" and setup like a Primary and all the images was seve to the data base

Thank you everyone and sorry